# How to hide path location, when using external Javascript to update HTML with external text document

Tags: javascript, text, xmlhttprequest, hide, src

I am working on getting a dynamic page set up on my site where clicking a "More Info" button triggers a `loadBCW.js` script which updates a `<div>`'s innerHTML using a text file saved elsewhere.  I've got that working perfectly using this `loadBCW.js`:

```
document.getElementById("loadBCW").addEventListener('click',function(){
var url = "/wp-content/themes/DICE/js/descriptionBCW";
var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML =
  this.responseText;
  }
};
xhttp.open("GET", url, true);
xhttp.send();
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = url;
}, false);
```

My issue is, when I click one of the "More Info" buttons in order to change the `<div>`'s `innerHTML`, it will flash the variable `url` in the `<div>`, then the correct elements overwrite it.

How can I instruct js to NOT flash the variable `url` onscreen before actually updating the `<div>`?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe get rid of the code that sets the div content to be the URL in the first place? I've commented out the line you should remove:

```
document.getElementById("loadBCW").addEventListener('click',function(){
    var url = "/wp-content/themes/DICE/js/descriptionBCW";
    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
            document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML =
            this.responseText;
        }
    };
    xhttp.open("GET", url, true);
    xhttp.send();
    // document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = url;
}, false);
```

You're making an asynchronous request to an external source, so the code inside the `xhttp.onreadystatechange` won't run until the file was successfully retrieved. There's not really anything you can do about this other than optimize your site to run faster than . So if you don't want the URL to be visible, there's no point in setting it in the first place.

However, this would be even worse if it was a sync request, as not only will it slow you performance, but since `document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = url;` is *after* your function, it is guaranteed to end by replacing the content with the URL.

Comment: Ah!  Removing that bit at least didn't HURT.  It might have made the text appear for a shorter amount of time, too.

Comment: Oops, didn't realize hitting enter would send the comment.  I had smashed together a few scripts to get to that one, and hadn't realized that it was actually extraneous.